# Android Studio Cmake build error: invalid conversion between vector type

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, clang, llvm

Hi currently I am having issue with building project using Android Studio and cmake. I was looking for solution here at stackoverflow but nothing came out of search. So heres the chunk of compile log where it fails.

```
[162/208] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o
[163/208] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_main.c.o
[164/208] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_net_chan.c.o
[165/208] Building C object CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_roq.c.o
FAILED: /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -DCURL_STATICLIB -DFEATURE_ANTICHEAT -DFEATURE_AUTOUPDATE -DFEATURE_DBMS -DFEATURE_EDV -DFEATURE_FREETYPE -DFEATURE_GETTEXT -DFEATURE_IRC_CLIENT -DFEATURE_MULTIVIEW -DFEATURE_OGG_VORBIS -DFEATURE_RATING -DFEATURE_RENDERER_GLES -DFEATURE_THEORA -DHAVE_SDL -DUSE_ICON -Iinclude -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2 -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fvisibility=hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -ffast-math -std=gnu89 -fPIE -MD -MT CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o   -c /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/cl_keys.c
In file included from /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/cl_keys.c:37:
In file included from /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/../sdl/sdl_defs.h:38:
In file included from /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38:
In file included from /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:64:
In file included from /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/immintrin.h:28:
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:64:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:143:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:173:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:203:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:230:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:253:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:274:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:301:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:324:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:345:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:366:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:387:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:408:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:430:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:453:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:475:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:497:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:518:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:539:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
FAILED: /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -DCURL_STATICLIB -DFEATURE_ANTICHEAT -DFEATURE_AUTOUPDATE -DFEATURE_DBMS -DFEATURE_EDV -DFEATURE_FREETYPE -DFEATURE_GETTEXT -DFEATURE_IRC_CLIENT -DFEATURE_MULTIVIEW -DFEATURE_OGG_VORBIS -DFEATURE_RATING -DFEATURE_RENDERER_GLES -DFEATURE_THEORA -DHAVE_SDL -DUSE_ICON -Iinclude -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2 -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fvisibility=hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -ffast-math -std=gnu89 -fPIE -MD -MT CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_main.c.o   -c /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/cl_main.c
In file included from /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/cl_main.c:42:
In file included from /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/../sys/sys_loadlib.h:52:
In file included from /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/../sys/../sdl/sdl_defs.h:38:
In file included from /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38:
In file included from /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:64:
In file included from /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/immintrin.h:28:
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:64:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:143:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:173:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:203:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:230:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:253:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:274:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:301:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:324:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:345:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:366:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:387:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:408:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:430:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:453:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:475:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:497:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:518:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/7.0.2/include/mmintrin.h:539:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Does it have to do with building executable file or is it some compile flag that messing thing up ?

```
FAILED: /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -DCURL_STATICLIB -DFEATURE_ANTICHEAT -DFEATURE_AUTOUPDATE -DFEATURE_DBMS -DFEATURE_EDV -DFEATURE_FREETYPE -DFEATURE_GETTEXT -DFEATURE_IRC_CLIENT -DFEATURE_MULTIVIEW -DFEATURE_OGG_VORBIS -DFEATURE_RATING -DFEATURE_RENDERER_GLES -DFEATURE_THEORA -DHAVE_SDL -DUSE_ICON -Iinclude -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/SDL2 -isystem /home/rafal/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fvisibility=hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -ffast-math -std=gnu89 -fPIE -MD -MT CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/etl.dir/src/client/cl_keys.c.o   -c /home/rafal/Pulpit/etlegacy/src/client/cl_keys.c
```

Comment: Aren't those all x86 intrinsics? They shouldn't be used on ARM64 if that's the case.

Comment: They are to be precised MMX instructions

Comment: Which are not supported on ARM64, right?

Comment: Yes they aren't

Comment: Then I guess I'm confused about what your question is. You can see the include stack that got you here in the error log. One of those headers (SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h, by the look of it, which is **not** a part of the NDK so I don't know why it's in your NDK directory) is wrongly including x86 specific things for arm64 and needs to not do that.

Comment: Ok I solved issue here. I had to reconfigure sdl-config.h with using cmake and android-toolchain.cmake to enable android options in it. Also turn off MMX and SSE options there. And now it compiles without errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your compiler from **clang** to **gcc** in your make files.

change

```
CC = clang
```

into

```
CC = gcc
```

Reference goes here: https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan/issues/321#issuecomment-362173825

Comment: But there is 1 problem Android Studio does not longer support make it is using ninja as it (default) build system. I did checked build.ninja file but there was no CC to set for. Also Cmake did set it as -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja

Comment: Also checked android_toolchain and there is a line saying that GCC is no longer supported

Comment: `Android NDK, Revision 16b (December 2017)` is the last version support gcc, if your project allows, you can try to use this revision.